# Problems with connecting to postgres

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, qt

Two problems occurred in sequence when connecting to the `postgres` database.

The first is the `QPSQL driver not loaded error`. I managed to solve it by adding qt `.dll files` to the project folder:

[image]

Then a problem appeared with the inability to connect to the database.

```
inline bool createConnection(){
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("ed_sim");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("89256328258i");
    db.setPort(5432);
    if(!db.open()){
        QMessageBox::warning(0, "Database error", "Connection with BD!");
        qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Connect", "Great");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

[image]

When launched, the `qDebug` line displays:

```
 connection to server at \"127.0.0.1\", port 5432 failed: ?????:
 ???????????? \"postgres\" ?? ?????? ??????? ?????????? (??
 ??????)\nQPSQL: Unable to connect
```

To fix it, I changed the `port` and `HostName`.
The result remained the same.

Comment: Fix your encoding problem.  You will have a miserable experience if all your messages are rendered in gibberish.

Comment: In the mean time, look in the db server's log file to see if the message there is readable.

Comment: Since the windows console is bad in outputting anything except the current locale I would suggest you to print the error text into a QMessageBox so it's readable and you can see what's really going wrong.